# Block mean value hashing method

Tags: image, image-processing, hash

In [Block Mean Value Based Image Perceptual Hashing](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4041692) Bian Yang proposed a hashing method which says:

The first perceptual hashing function is based on the mean

```
a) Normalize the original image into a preset sizes;

b) Divide the size-normalized image I into non overlapped blocks I1, I2, …, IN, 
in which N is the block number equal to length of the final hash bit string;

c) Calculate the mean value sequence {M1, M2, …, MN} from corresponding 
block sequence {I’1, I’2, …, I’N } and obtain the median value Md of 
this sequence as: Md = median (Mi) (i=1,2,…, N) 

d) Normalize the mean value sequence into a binaryform and obtain the hash 
values h as:
h(i)=0 if Mi<Md
h(i)=1 if Mi>= Md
```

My Question is on part "b", any one knows how the image is divided into blocks? is it something like this?
[image]

Comment: Did I get the paper right ?

Comment: If the "length of the final hash bit string" is 32, then the division in 32 blocks like you showed is right. This step could be better described actually, if it only requires 32 non-overlapping blocks, then I can pick the first 31 pixels as one block each, and the remaining of the image as the last block. I don't think you would want to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Yep you're right. Most implementations do the blocks in 32 spread-out non-overlaping blocks for general image hashing, but, you could also identify a face and hash that as well, or if you know there is extra detail somewhere specifically, like text at the bottom, dedicate more blocks there.

You can see a full implementation in JS here: https://github.com/danm/image-hash/blob/master/src/block-hash.ts
(part of the image-hash npm, which cites the same paper you're referring to).

The main idea is to just condense the visual information of an image into something much smaller and fixed-size (so that you can use fixed-size hash compares quickly).

The order of the blocks doesn't matter in any way to the algorithm, the only thing that matters is you use the same order when making comparisons, since the order changes the hash output.

Also, as you mentioned in your comment, it only cares that the blocks don't overlap. It's going to compute the median for the blocks in the end, so, most implementations will produce the same output if you give it an 8k version of an image, or a 32x32 pixel version of an image, because they spread the blocks out in the exact way you did (although they may change directions and go left to right or something).